# Grouping list of objects based on variable attributes of object in java

Tags: guava

I need to do group by on list of objects based multiple attributes in the object.

like lets say there is a student object

with attributes name,number,state,city,marks

now i need to do group by on it based on multiple keys,

like

it cab be state,city or state or name,state,city or marks,count(*)

Please let me know the best option to do it.

the possible options i have are.

1) using of Nested maps
2) using multimap with composite key
3) using ArrayTable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just do a list per criteria. Otherwise I might create an Enum that implements `Predicate` and create a `Multimap` with the enum as the key.

Comment: I don't have any restriction on number of criteria. it can be any combination of attributes in the object depends on request. This means i can't create list per Criteria.. Don't know about google Predicate..can you please let me know how can i decide on Enum